# How can i extract values from promise and send them to client via node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a promise that returns data and I want to pass values of the promise as a response to client(web browser). I know i should probably use asynchronous js, but I'm not sure how to do that. Could you please give me some advice?

Here is how it looks like:

```
if(req.url === "/api/posts"){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
    let db = new AppDAO('./db/db.sqlite3') 
    const postsDb = new PostsRepository(db)
    let posts = postsDb.getAll() 
    db.close()
    console.log(posts)
    res.end()
}
```

Comment: What's `PostsRepository`, and what does `PostsRepository#getAll` return?

Comment: You can't get anything out of a promise until the promise is resolved. Use promises as the documentation tells you to.

Comment: PostsRepository#getAll returns promise, PostsRepository is just database object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to build the response when the DB `Promise` resolves

```
postsDb.getAll().then(posts => {
    console.log(posts)
    res.send(posts)
}).finally(() => db.close())
```

Or if you want to use the modern syntax, and can declare the surrounding function as `async`:

```
try {
    const posts = await postsDb.getAll()
    console.log(posts)
    res.send(posts)
} catch(e) {
    // Handle database error
} finally {
    db.close()
}
```

Comment: That `db.close` really aught to be in a `finally`, otherwise there may be connection leaks on query failures.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.